# API for pulling public images based on geo location (lat lng)

Tags: google-maps, instagram-api, flickr, photo-gallery, panoramio

Looking for the best api to pull public images based on geo - lat/lng for a cycling travel website.  I use Panoramio but I hear it is closing so assume the API will disappear soon.  Also looking for code samples for implementation.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Under the "What topics can I ask about" I saw it include "software tools commonly used by programmers" - and the specific problem I have is that the software tool I use, in this case Panoramio APIs, are (I think) going away.  That's a pretty specific problem for me.  I do understand that this isn't a specific coding issue - but I'm desperate and frankly can't find any info anywhere.  If there's a better forum I'd love to know...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't necessarily call it the "best" API for your purposes, but since the question is tagged with the Flickr API: the [flickr.photos.search](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) endpoint does support lat and lon search options.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have experience with any other APIs - or better yet code samples?